# How do you upload files larger than 1GB to an apache web server using php?

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, raspbian, lamp

Any file larger than around 1GB eventually gives me a "connection reset" error. I have tried every solution I could find online and nothing helped.

Smaller files upload just fine.

The server is a small home server running on a Raspberry Pi 4.

Here are the related settings in both the php.ini and the apache.conf:

php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 300000

max_input_time = 300000

max_input_nesting_level = 64

max_input_vars = 1000

memory_limit = 2048M

post_max_size = 300000M

file_uploads = On

upload_max_filesize = 300000M

max_file_uploads = 100
```

apache.conf:

```
RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500

Timeout 300000

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 300000
```

I have tried a variety of other options without success. I have restarted apache and rebooted the server. My apache.conf file does not contain a LimitRequestBody option.

Comment: What browser are you using? This could be a browser upload limit rather than an apache reset.

Comment: have you tried monitoring your server Ram usage while uploading the file?

Comment: Maybe your server is running out of memory? It's worth monitoring to see how that's holding up.

Comment: @LiamSorsby I am using Firefox and the file I am trying to upload is 1.9GB. It loads for about 10 minutes before giving me a "Connection Reset" error.

Comment: @SviesusAlus The ram usage doesn't even appear to change, the CPU usage spikes but not terribly high. The servers memory appears fine.

Comment: on PHP receiving function do `set_time_limit(200000);` and try again. whats the result?

Comment: @chunchunmaru I believe Firefox max upload is either 2gb or 1gb. I'd attempt to send the file via curl to rule out a browser limit

Comment: Your other option is to use wireshark to check what's sending the reset packet.

Comment: I will try @SviesusAlus suggestion first while still using my browser, as it should just about be able to upload this file size, because it takes about 10 minutes of loading before I even get the error. I will try curl after that.

Comment: also after that try removing `RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500` cause this looks fishy too. or better do `RequestReadTimeout header=0 body=0`

Comment: I added the set_time_limit and tried to upload without success, same result when removing or changing the RequestReadTimeout.

Comment: I installed chrome as it is supposed to support files around 4GB in size for uploading. It also gives me a progress indicator.

Comment: I believe I have found the issue. The raspberry pi ARM processor is 32bit, therefore 32bit php is being used. Apparently 32bit php doesn't support files larger than 2GB. I will try and find a way to split the files into smaller sizes during upload.